# What is the resistance band's elastic length

Tags: exercise, strength, gym, exercise-equipment, resistance-cord

I have a new set of [Resistance cord](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008L61G0I) that I bought.
Assuming that all brand resistance tubes are quite similar, what is the length of extension that I can give to it?

Each cord is of 4 feet length.
While doing a few exercise, I am required to pull it overhead(while standing), placing the cord under my feet and using both hands to pull. I am 5 feet 8 inches tall.

I am afraid I will break the cord and injure myself while exercising.
Hope this is not off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all bands are the same.  If the cord is made for the purpose of exercise, then the band simply won't stretch anymore if you are at the end of its elasticity.  I can't tell you what that length is for the cord you purchased.

I use ["Iron Woody" bands](http://www.roguefitness.com/iron-woody-bands.php), and the loop is about 4 ft.  These bands can easily handle the type of exercise you are talking about.  In fact they can also be used for accommodating resistance for barbell exercises.  There will be no worry about the bands breaking under normal use.

Again, I haven't handled or examined the bands you purchased up close.  If they do break, the chance of serious injury for your resistance band exercises will be very low.  I recommend testing out the stretch by the exercise you described.  They won't break on the first use.  If they have reached their elastic limits and prevent you from doing the exercise you need to do, I wouldn't trust them to maintain integrity for very long like that.  However, if you can perform the exercise and they feel like they can handle even more stretch you will be OK.

Comment: Additionally as bands age, they lose their elasticity. This can be accelerated by exposure to extreme environments (Keeping it in the garage), or simple unuse. Think of a newspaper rubber band that is old, they get extremely brittle.

Comment: Where do you get the idea, that the risk of injury is low? This bands might be under a lot of tension. If it hits you in the wrong body part injuries might be severe. I know a person who lost an eye that way.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used those resistive narrow bands meant to assist traditional barbell exercises, but I have worked as an assistant to two physical therapists, and I remember hearing the advice given to patients to not stretch a Thera band (used in occupational therapy) to over 3 times the band's length.  It is confirmed on the band usage manual too.

Comment: Thank you. Useful answer, even though it is late.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my resistance rope, I thought I will give my own version too.

I bought [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008L61G0I) some 5 months ago.
Yesterday, while sitting on a 2 feet wall and performing a shoulder exercise, the red rope (level 3 rope) broke. Not much of an injury except for a little bruises on hand & feet.

I would have stretched the rope to some 10 feet approx. After having regularly used the rope for some 5 months, it could have had some wear and tear.

So, I recommend people to buy resistance ropes, only after knowing the stretch or elastic limit.
If they aren't mentioned anywhere on the product, please don't buy. While exercising, it may lead to severe injury. You may even lose an eye. Beware!